# Two update on a single statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have two update statements that we run on SQL server they are like

```
UPDATE dbo.c_Account
SET Ct = Ct-1
Where 
Acc = 'IT' OR Acc = 'gt'

UPDATE dbo.c_Account
SET Ct = Ct-3
Where 
Acc = 'ABC'
```

Is there a possibility of doing the both update on one single statement

Comment: sound like case statement

Comment: Are you trying to reduce code? Seeing a performance issue?

Comment: @dfundako I am new to SQL server and queries I can do them separately but not sure just one statement can do the both

Comment: can you please paste the structure of the table it will be helpful

Comment: @trx I'll let Yashveer submit his answer since its correct.  It wont be shorter code wise (or very close), but it can be done in one operation and it will be all or nothing instead of 2 separate, atomic processes.

Comment: @trx thanks . I posted

Comment: These statements can be combined, but--depending on how large the tables are, and how they are indexed, it can perform poorly. (`where` clauses containing `or` statements generally require table scans, and SQL usually converts `in` clauses to multiple `or` clauses.)

Comment: You can put them together but that does not mean they will run faster.  What you have is just fine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could combine it like this:

```
UPDATE t SET
    Ct = Ct - CASE WHEN t.Acc IN ('IT','gt') THEN 1 ELSE 3 END
FROM dbo.c_Account t
WHERE t.Acc IN ('IT','gt','ABC')
```

There is little benefit, except that it now will run as one atomic operation, and does not require an outer transaction.

Answer (score 1):

```
     UPDATE dbo.c_Account
     SET Ct  = case Acc when 'IT' then  (Ct-1 )
     when 'GT' then ct-1
     when 'abc' then  ct-3
     else ct
     end

  WHERE t.Acc IN ('IT','gt','ABC')
```

Comment: You get points when your answer gets up votes or gets marked as the accepted answer by the person who posted the question.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE dbo.c_Account
SET Ct = case
when (Acc = 'IT' OR Acc = 'gt') then Ct-1
When Acc = 'ABC' then Ct-3
Else ct
End
```

Above will update all records with default not changing. You could add a where statment to only update the ones you need e.g.
    Where acc in ('IT','gt','ABC')

Comment: While this will give you the correct result, it also could lead to a massive operation if the table has 100,000,000 rows.

Comment: I agree,  it was to demonstrate how it can be achieved. I posted before adding the comment with the where clause (still finding my way around stackoverflow :) )